# Extract RFM results generated by 'rfm' package - R

Tags: r

I have used `rfm_table_customer` of the `rfm` package and stored the result in an object named `rfm_results`. I got problems extracting the data:

1, When I check `rfm_results` in the console, I have a tibble of 24056 rows and that is the correct number of customers in my input data. But when I try `View(rfm_results)`, I get this error:

> "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 24056"

2, When I try to extract a segment using the following:

```
Champions <- rfm_results %>% 
  filter(recency_score >= 4, frequency_score >= 4, monetary_score >= 4)
```

I get this error:

> "Columns `rfm`, `analysis_date` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists"

How can I use `rfm_results` like a normal tibble or data frame? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the output of `rfm_table_customer` is composed by "multiple outputs": a hint about it is this, try

```
> class(rfm_results)
[1] "rfm_table_order" "tibble"          "data.frame"
```

So for your first question:

```
View(rfm_results$rfm)
```

And for your second question:

```
Champions <- rfm_result$rfm %>%
             filter(recency_score >= 4, frequency_score >= 4, monetary_score >= 4)
```